# Add Layer Groups fron a json file

Tags: javascript, json, leaflet

I've been making this map for my d&d party using leaflet. The map was easily done with `L.CRS.Simple`

Since i plan for lots of markers to be added to the map i created a JSON file called `spotsData.json` within the project with each markers info:

```
]
        {
            "locationName": "Mysterious Symbol",
            "locationDescription": "Fengil's people are heading towards what looks to be a abandoned library. What could the symbol really mean?",
            "lat": 759,
            "lng": 156,
            "group": "Places Of Interest"
        },
        {
            "locationName": "Session 17",
            "locationDescription": "Fengil calls Kargro after finding his people and decides to turn in his power to keep it safe as it was always meant to be.",
            "lat": 489,
            "lng": 655,
            "group": "Previous Sessions"
        }
]
```

Ive been successful with looping over the markers and giving them their values:

```
    async function mapSpotsToMap() {
    const spotsData = await (await fetch('./spotsData.json')).json();
    
      for (let spot of spotsData) {;
        // Lat and Lng
        let position = L.latLng([spot.lat, spot.lng]);
      
        //Colours
        let colour;
        switch (spot.group) {
          case "Cities": 
            colour = red;
            break;
          case "Places Of Interest":
            colour = grey; 
            break;
          case "Towns":
            colour = violet; 
            break;
          case "Previous Sessions":
            colour = blue; 
            break;
          default:
            colour = grey;
        }
        L.marker(position, {icon: colour}).bindPopup('<b>'+spot.locationName+'</b><p>'+spot.locationDescription+'</p>').addTo(map);;
    }
}
```

But I'm completely stumped on how to use `L.layerGroup` and `L.control.layers` within my loop to add markers to groups based on their `"group":`

How can this be accomplished or is there a better way i could be doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well im not sure if this was the best way to do this but i found the solution after thinking on it.

By using a similar switch statement i used for the colors i could add markers to their group based on the value of their group

```
let marker = L.marker(position, {icon: colour}).bindPopup('<h3>'+spot.locationName+'</h3><h4>Type: '+spot.group+'</h4><p>'+spot.locationDescription+'</p>');

        //Group
        switch (spot.group) {
          case "Places Of Interest":
            marker.addTo(Places_Of_Interest);
            break;
          case "Previous Sessions":
            marker.addTo(Previous_Sessions);
            break;
        }
    }
    var overlays = {
      "Places of interest" : Places_Of_Interest,
      "Previous Sessions" : Previous_Sessions,
    }
    L.control.layers(null, overlays).addTo(map)
```